# Prove that $A$ is a compact linear operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-writing, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, compact-operators

> Prove that for a given two-variable polynomial function $a, $ the operator $A : L^{\infty} \left ([0,1], m \right ) \longrightarrow  L^{\infty} \left ([0,1], m \right )$ (where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure) defined by $$Af(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} a(x,y) f(y)\ dy$$  is compact.

How do I proceed? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show, when $a$ is a monomial, that $A$ has finite rank.

Comment: Oh! Do you mean @Mindlack that $A(L^{\infty})$ has finite dimension?

Comment: What I see is that if $a(x,y) = \displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij} x^{k_i} y^{l_j}$ then we have $$Af(x) = \displaystyle  \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij} x^{k_i} \int_{0}^{1} y^{l_j} f(y)\ dy.$$

Comment: Yes... so $Af$ is always a polynomial of bounded degree...

Comment: That means $Af$ can be written as a $\Bbb R$-linear combination of $f_1,f_2, \cdots, f_m$ where $f_i (x) = x^{k_i},\ x \in [0,1],$ for $i=1,2, \cdots, m$ where each $f_i \in L^{\infty} \left ([0,1], m \right )$ since $\|f_i\|_{\infty} = 1 \lt \infty.$ Am I right @Mindlack?